# Is it possible to restore an image from Acronis into a single partition, instead of the whole disk?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, acronis-trueimage, imaging

I haven't worked with Acronis yet (or any other OS cloning software), but as far as I know, it has to be restored on a blank HDD instead of a single partition (out of 2 or more).

So, is that possible to restore a backup image into one partition within the disk keeping the other partition intact?

PS: Also, if you can provide me a simple tutorial of how to use Acronis TI, I would be thankful for that as well. ;)

Oh yes, I also need to know if it's possible to create an "Universal" image. That way I could restore the image into any machine (no matter which other drivers should be used). Sorry, I'm a real newbie to this.

Comment: For the 'Universal Image' you need the Pro version of Acronis. But you could use AOMEI Backupper where that function comes in the free version. http://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html

Comment: @whs Acronis Home version now comes with Universal Restore thrown in.

Comment: @whs and Tetsujin Thanks, that info really helps. I highly appreciate that as a newbie. =P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are both possible in Acronis. it doesn't matter whether you've backed up your entire drive, one partition or even some files/folders, you can either restore the whole backup image or some files/folders in it. you can also specify where you want your image be restored. for better results you better do the backup/restore using bootable media instead of in the OS itself.

Here are the steps:

1. Boot your system with Acronis bootable media (you can create it in the Tools in Acronis)
2. At the startup, boot to your bootable media and select the option "Acronis True Image". Your system will reboot using Acronis True Image bootable media.
3. On the opened window, under the Recover section, click My Disks to recover your system drive.
4. On the next window, click Browse and locate the backup file .TIB extension.
5. Once located, back on the previous window, click Next.
6. On Choose recovery method window, you have multiple options to either select  Recover whole disk, partitions or some files/folders.
7. in the next step to specify destination folder, you can choose where you want to save/recover your files. it can be a folder you've already created, a partition or the whole HDD.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I've added the information.

Comment: Thanks, that should help me with the most I need. Erm.. Would it be much if I ask you for a demonstrative video?

Comment: I'm glad, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btLbZzozado) will show you how to setup your Acronis and follow the steps above.